# Adding a score counter to rock, paper, scissors

Tags: python

That is my code for a rock, paper, scissors game in CodeSkulptor 3 and I need help adding a tally or score counter!

```
ppeepepepepepooopoppoopp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep scores in dedicated variables (`score_user`, `score_comp`) and update them on each iteration.
Also you can improve your script by replacing all `if-else` statements with `MAP` list:

```
import random

ACTIONS = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']
MAP = [['=', '<', '>'],
       ['>', '=', '<'],
       ['<', '>', '=']]
SCORE = {'=': ['Tied Game!', 0, 0],
         '>': ['WINNER!', 1, 0],
         '<': ['You Lost.', 0, 1]}

score_user = 0
score_comp = 0
play = 'yes'
while play == 'yes':
    user = ACTIONS.index(input(f'Type your choice {ACTIONS}: '))
    comp = random.randint(0, 2)
    print(f'You chose {ACTIONS[user]}, computer chose {ACTIONS[comp]}.')
    res = MAP[user][comp]
    score_user += SCORE[res][1]
    score_comp += SCORE[res][2]
    print(f'{ACTIONS[user].title()} {res} {ACTIONS[comp].title()}. {SCORE[res][0]} Your score: {score_user}. Comp score: {score_comp}')
    play = input('Play again? yes or no: ')
```

Output:

```
Type your choice ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']: rock
You chose rock, computer chose scissors.
Rock > Scissors. WINNER! Your score: 1. Comp score: 0
Play again? yes or no: yes
Type your choice ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']: paper
You chose paper, computer chose scissors.
Paper < Scissors. You Lost. Your score: 1. Comp score: 1
Play again? yes or no: no
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add:

```
scores = [0, 0]
```

at the start of the project to initialise the values. Then, under your player win conditions:

```
scores[0] += 1
```

and underneath the computer win conditions:

```
scores[1] += 1
```

and finally, if you wanted to print the scores, use this line:

```
print(f'Player Score: {scores[0]}, Computer Score: {scores[1]}')
```